# Prettier not working on VS Code (only from Command Palette)

Tags: vscode-extensions, prettier

I'm using VS Code on Windows 11, and I have installed Prettier. However, it only works from the terminal.

If I execute `npx Prettier --write dom.html` in the terminal, it works fine.

If I go to the Command Palette and choose `Format Document`, the following error appears in the output:

```
["ERROR" - 10:38:49 AM] Invalid prettier configuration file detected.
["ERROR" - 10:38:49 AM] ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'c:\Users\ivanf\Dropbox\dev\FrontEndBootCamp - Exercises\firstjs\ C:\Users\ivanf\AppData\Roaming\npm\prettier'
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'c:\Users\ivanf\Dropbox\dev\FrontEndBootCamp - Exercises\firstjs\ C:\Users\ivanf\AppData\Roaming\npm\prettier'
```

To make it more clear,

`c:\Users\ivanf\Dropbox\dev\FrontEndBootCamp - Exercises\firstjs\` is the project folder, and
`\Users\ivanf\AppData\Roaming\npm\prettier` is where prettier is installed.

So it seems that in some configuration file the wrong path "$PROJECT_FOLDER $PRETTIER_HOME" is formed.

Unfortunately, I cannot locate such file, and I cannot understand why it does work when called from the terminal.

I've been looking through all .json files, and uninstalled and installed again both VS Code and Prettier, and of course I made sure everything is up to date.

And I also installed Prettier ESlint, but nothing changed.
Working on Windows 11, by the way.

Any advice or hints?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is prettier installed globally on your system? Try running `npm uninstall -g prettier` do delete it, and let VSCode reinstall it for you with the prettier extension.

Comment: Done it. No changes, same issue.
Actually, this is how I first installed Prettier, I forgot to mention.
When it didn't work, I installed it globally as well.